# app closed and reopen still saved instance is null ? why

Tags: android

I try to open the app again `saveinstance` still is null
and my code is correct? thanks for your answer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView cc;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      cc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Oncreate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

       cc.setText( "=++++++++++++++");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OnCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        cc.setText("kkkkkkkkkk");




    }
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){

    Toast.makeText(this,"onSavedInstance",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    out.putString("checking", "checking");

    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

}
```

Comment: because when you closed app at that time onDestroy() called not onResume() and you reopen the app at that time onCreate() will be call

Comment: saveinstance do no survive after closing app . Read the documentation. For this you need to use persitent database(Database or SharedPreference).